# Math 2D graphs: best way of graphically (black and white or using colors) representing overlapping curves

Tags: color-scheme, graphic-design, graphs, math

what's the best way to represent multiple 2D Cartesian-style graphs drawn in the same Caryesian plane and having zero or more possibly intersecting parts of intersection length 0 to open or closed k or infinity. How to do this (a): using one color, (b): using shades of gray, including or excluding white and or black, (c):using a disjoint set of perceptually distinct colors, (d) using any combination of (perceptually distinct or related) colors.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to do your own homework assignments.

This creates the best user experience, as you can check your knowledge, test your ability, learn from the process, and understand any mistakes you make.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Overlapping graph segments? What's the best way to represent these graphically. Your typical homework assignments have a few curves overlapping at most at single points on the plane, not at entire line segments as I described it.